# Outlook 2007 Vista: still receiving email from deleted gmail account

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I have recently given my vista laptop to my husband and deleted my gmail email address from his outlook so it only receives his emails.  However, even tho the gmail address is not showing up in the accounts list, outlook is still receiving emails for this account.  How do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: What accounts are configured? You may have something setup on the GMAIL side that is forwarding emails received from GMAIL to the account currently configured in Outlook

Answer (score 1):

One way to see how emails arrived in Outlook is to [view the message headers](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/view-e-mail-message-headers-HA001230300.aspx)

You'll see a series of headers like:

```
Received: from mail.litwareinc.com ([10.54.108.101]) 
by mail.proseware.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.0);
Wed, 15 Dec 2004 13:39:22 -0800

Received: from mail ([10.54.108.23] RDNS failed) 
by mail.litware.com with Microsoft SMTPSVC(6.0.3790.0);
Wed, 15 Dec 2004 13:38:49 -0800
```

Often this will give you some clues as to what is happening.

I would also check all the details for each account configured in Outlook.